Do we need a multiple-recipient(-encryption) tag?
Do we need a multi-recipient or multi-recipient-encryption tag? That would be used for MRES (Multiple-Recipient Encryption Scheme) specific questions?
I think that MRES and related acronyms (MRSES for symmetric encryption) are too hard to find. We could of course later decide to add these as synonyms if we think they're needed.
This related to the question I asked here about a MRES in combination with ECIES / RSA-KEM.

Yes, create the tag multi-recipient-encryption. StackExchange is generally in favor of more specific tags anyway.

Yes, create the tag multiple-recipient. The fact that it is about encryption or message authentication is probably clear from other tags or context.

Nah, why would we need such a tag? We didn't need it before and I don't think we need it now.
